# Access Telerik RadGrid CommandItemTemplate controls

Tags: c#, telerik, telerik-grid

How to find controls in telerik radgrid CommandItemTemplate?

I've tried this:

GridItem commandItem = RadGrid1.MasterTableView.GetItems(GridItemType.CommandItem)[0];

But it throws exception: "Index was outside the bounds of the array."

MasteTableView's CommandItemDisplay property is set to "Top".

Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I do not see any flaws in your code. Post forum or support ticket on the telerik site to get further insight from the telerik crew.